# Installing a New Electrical Outlet in a Modified Closet?

Tags: electrical

I have a closet that I've modified to be a vanity area (I have 2 closets and aren't interested in having a titanic wardrobe). I pulled off the closet doors and the closet clothing hanging hardware and made a floating desk.

The only thing I need is power for the blow dryer and lights I plan on adding. I've decided that a old work 3 gang box would be best (Having a duplex for electronics, and a light switch for the overhead lights).
Desk:
[image: Desk]

Intended Place for 3-Gang:
[image: 3-Gang Location]

I plan on using the typical daisy-chain tactic between existing outlets in my room.

**Closet Considerations:**

I was reading some other posts about installing outlets in a closet (And objections to it, notably regarding closets being used to store objects and the outlet/objects plugged into the outlet being crushed, and I don't think that will apply here since this area will not be used for storage.

**Code Considerations:**
I'm not entirely certain how to wire the outlet up to code, and could certainly use some instruction with regard to this. I've chosen 14 AWG Romex wire for the install (Same as the already existing outlet). I know that I've seen contractors use electrical tape to wrap the screw terminals around the outlets, but what else would be involved in this installation? I also need to run wire behind the wall to get from one outlet to the other. I plan on following an install similar to for running the wire(https://youtu.be/eSMUnuoxdZQ).

What are the minimum requirements to wire a new code-compliant outlet like this in a closet?

Comment: Decided to do that just to make sure i was in the ampacity range. I'll probably change it to #14. Revised question to be more specific in what I was asking for.

Comment: To be clear, you need to check the breaker rating and existing wiring before you can decide what wire to use.

Comment: @isherwood 15A Already checked.

Comment: In that video, they stick an "old work" box directly to drywall.  I'd be cautious about that. Drywall is super fragile.  It's fine for light switches like the video shows, but a new receptacle and new plug can be quite stiff and be a wrestling match to insert or remove.  It can tear the old-work box right out of the drywall.   I would aim to use an old-work box that screws to the edge of a stud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a 3 gang box with 12 AWG wire I would not use a plastic old work box the tabs are not large enough. I would use a metal box with wings the wings expand among each side, they come in single gang that 1 side can be removed off each end box and both sides on the center box then they attach to each other. Screwing to a stud as Harper suggest is also a good idea. I have no problem installing outlets in a closets I have added some for things like dehumidifiers many times. The lighting you are going to need to be careful with because this is a closet look at NEC 410.16.C for the type you can use in a closet and the allowable locations.